# Addtocart not working

Tags: magento-2.1

Add to cart is not working. When I had product to cart then it display message like

```
 You have no items in your shopping cart.
 Click here to continue shopping.
```

I tried,

```
  Stores -> Configuration -> Web -> Default Cookie Settings -> Cookie Lifetime = 86400
```

But still no effect.

Comment: Are you working on localhost ?

Comment: @Prince - yes I work on localhost

Answer (score 0):

Please try the first, if it doesn't work try again the second:

1- Enable caches.

2- Check if there are two cookies are setting with same name: one for `domainname.com` and another for `www.domainname.com`. then need to change the cookie domain to `www.domainname.com` in Admin cookie settings, So that 2nd cookie disappeared and it will works as expected.

Comment: Cookie path and cookie domain are blank in admin.

Comment: Have you activated the caches ?

Comment: Yes, I have activated the caches.

Comment: Try to put your `www.domainname.com` in  cookie domain

Comment: My domain name is  - http://localhost/Magento/ then put www.Magento.com

Comment: I think the problem comes from here, anyway it is a problem of cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the admin panel: Sytem -> Configuration -> Web -> Session and Cookie Management

Set Cookie Lifetime to 86400 and save. The functionality will work as expected.

Also, check your form key in app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml

Code for form key: getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>

If not available then add after this: getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">

Comment: I am using magento 2 in that till now I didnot use any theme. I am using the default one.